# Reportgenerator skips particular project coverage when converting to Cobertura and Sonar formats

Tags: reportgenerator

Strangely noticed, that for my solution with 100+ projects, one of them is skipped by Reporgenerator.

I convert the raw report generated by dotCover into 3 formats: Cobertura, SonarQube and HtmlInline_AzurePipelines.

Interesting fact, that coverage for this project do exist in HTML report, but both Cobertura and SonarQube don't show it up. The rest projects are being exported correctly (from the first glance) to all aforementioned formats.

Did anyone see this 'magic' before?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please open an issue [here](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=):

Some more details would be helpful.
Can you share your coverage files and the name of the missing project?
You can also send the coverage files privately by email (see issue template).

Comment: Sure, will do soon